# Titanium Oxydifluoride

Tags: x-rays

In the X-Ray powder diffraction study of titanium oxydifluoride the data, when indexed, gives the structure as simple cubic. Putting the titaniums at the eight corners of the unit cell gives 8 x 1/8 = 1 (Ti); assumed fluorines at centres of each edge giving 8 x 1/4 = 2 (F); one oxygen in the centre = TiOF2.
It turns out that the structure is simple cubic but inside the unit cell tere is an octahedron of O2F4 (Shian & Sandhage; Applied Crystallography, 757-761; 2009).
How would the student realise that when the indexed data only indicates simple cubic ?

Comment: Well, how does the Applied Crystallography article analyze it?

Answer (score 0):

The positions of the lines in the powder pattern only tell you the lattice type and size. They cannot tell you the arrangement of atoms inside the cell (the *motif*).

However the relative intensities of the lines can be calculated from the motif. There is no way to go from the relative intensities to the motif, but given a motif you can calculate the line intensities and see if it matches your pattern.

So in this case the student could take their proposed structure, calculate the line intensities and see if it matched. However bear in mind that there is no guarantee that two different motifs would give sufficiently different line intensities to be distinguished.